# How can I create a transition between two subview iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, transition

I have a problem when I want to create a transition between to views inside a container view in iOS application. I want to create an animation that makes my first view goes out sliding to the left and the second coming from the right (like switching between photos, a sort of push in Navigation Controller). I created my animation but the problem is that my subview does not disappear once reached the border of my container view but when it reaches the edge of my screen.

I used this code:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = animationTime;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = transationSubtype;
[transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
transition.removedOnCompletion = YES;
[view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

[image]

As visible in the image the red square goes out from the screen and not from its container and also the green comes inside from the screen edge and not from the container view edge. I want instead that the animation ends when reaches the container view edge.

I tried anything but I was not able to find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set clipsToBounds property of the container view to YES